# AngularJS load module async

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

At internship, I've been assigned to make an AngularJS based application which should be displaying various small widgets. The basic process would be the following:

- Application starts, reads an API key from the URL.
- The API key is send via $http.get() to the API, which returns a list of widgets to display.
- The main controller loads these widgets their JS with RequireJS into the view.
- Widgets load their own data to display via the API using they key.
- Both the process of the application loading widgets and the widgets loading data are on a refresh timer.

Currently, I'm stuck with getting the widgets to display. While the components work properly stand-alone (the widgets themselves display data when manually placed into the body, and the application does receive the JSON correctly. Even including the JavaScript files using RequireJS based on the JSON calls goed perfectly as I've added `console.log()`s in the widget, and these display correctly after the AJAX calls.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get these widgets to load up after this first AJAX call?

Comment: A1 never was designed for it. Try ocLazyLoad. And the straightforward way is to bundle widgets with Webpack, etc. and load the whole thing synchronously.

Comment: Looking into ocLazyLoad ATM, does appear to be a solution to the problem. Using Webpack wouldn't help as this would basically require me to load all widgets and hide the ones I do not need. But assuming there's possibly going to be over 50 widgets, this is not a fast or optimal idea, thus Lazy loading.

Comment: Bundling and loading them at once is almost always more efficient than loading them one by one, performance-wise. Since Angular never intended to support lazy loading, ocLazyLoad is a hack and will result in many unobvious problems that require good understanding of how Angular works to fix them, but if it works for you, it's ok.

Comment: I'll see how it unfolds. As far as it goes, ocLazyLoad seems to have fixed the issue with the loading so far. Thanks for the suggestion @estus ^^